# Laravel : Can't use `Input::get('foobar')` as an action's default parameter value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to do the following in my controller:

```
public function moveMessagesToArchive( $message_ids = Input::get('message_ids') )
{
    $json = json_encode( $message_ids);
    echo $json;
}
```

And it keeps throwing the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'

at the function signature. What's causing the problem here?

**Update**

While, I wait for the reason I've written the following work around:

```
public function moveMessagesToArchive( $message_ids = array() )
{
    $ids =  array();

    if ( ( count($message_ids) !== 0 ) && is_array($message_ids) ) {
        $ids = $message_ids;
    } else if ( Input::get('message_ids') ) {
        $ids = Input::get('message_ids');
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $json = json_encode( $ids );
    echo $json;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in PHP. According to the documentation

```
The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.
```

[Reference Example 4](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not, and never has been supported by php.

Nothing at all to do with Laravel.